# how to set recyclerview adapter in fragment in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

[The below error is displayed.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jxals.png)

I'm trying to set the adapter on onViewCreated Lifecycle method in Fragment.

Comment: still need code how you did in your adapter

Comment: i have created a custom adapter .. 

public picture_Adapter(ArrayList<pictureFacer> pictureList, Context pictureContx,itemClickListener picListerner) {
        this.pictureList = pictureList;
        this.pictureContx = pictureContx;
        this.picListerner = picListerner;
    }

Comment: Please don't post only screenshots of your code and error. You can provide an image, as well, to better illustrate what you mean, but you need to also state exactly what the error is, and give the code, in text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In kotlin you don't have to use 'setAdapter' but instead you can just use adapter.
When trying to do this remember that it's not a function invocation.
Instead you can use it like this:

`imageRecyclerView.adapter = picture_Adapter(infos, this, this)`

Answer (score 1):

Try using image_recyclerview.adapter = picture_adapter(infos, this, this)

Comment: Glad I could help.